# Quick screen capture application

Tags: screen, capture

I'm looking for a quick screen capture application that simply brings up the screen selection tool (which part of the screen I want to capture) with some keybinding and saves it directly into some specified directory. In particular, I don't want any GUI to pop up. Has someone an application in mind that fulfills the above criteria?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of screenshot are you expecting? In which application will you use the screenshot app? What kind of features do you want? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which desktop environment are you using? Please [edit] to include all these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Gnome Screenshot

If you're using the gnome desktop then you can easily capture screenshot using these key-bindings

1. <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – Save a screenshot of the entire screen to the “Pictures” directory.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – Save a screenshot of a specific region to Pictures.
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>  – Save a screenshot of the current window to Pictures.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – Copy the screenshot of the entire screen to the clipboard.
5. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – Copy the screenshot of a specific region to the clipboard.
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – Copy the screenshot of the current window to the clipboard.

#### Flameshot

It is my personal favorite screenshot application, which can be installed using:

```
$ sudo apt install flameshot
```

By default, you need to launch it using GUI but you can easily set a screenshot for flameshot by following these steps:

1. Head to the system settings and navigate your way to the Keyboard settings.
2. You will find all the keyboard shortcuts listed there, ignore them and scroll down to the bottom. Now, you will find a `+` button.
3. Click the `+` button to add a custom shortcut.
4. You need to enter the following in the fields you get:
   Name: *Anything You Want*
   Command: `/usr/bin/flameshot gui`
5. Finally, set the shortcut to <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – which will warn you that the default screenshot functionality will be disabled – so proceed doing it. 
   <sup><sub>[Reference](https://itsfoss.com/take-screenshot-linux/)</sub></sup>

You can easily configure it to suite your needs. Just press <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> and it'll open a selection tool. Selct the desired area, do customizations and easily save it.

Features:

- Annotate (highlight, point, add text, box in)
- Blur part of an image
- Crop part of an image
- Upload to [Imgur](https://imgur.com)
- Open screenshot with another app

[image: Features]

You can easily press the save button to save the image. In the app settings, you can also choose the default directory to save images in. It also have a lot of customisable key-bindings and features.

Comment: thanks, the second one does it for me since I don't use the gnome desktop environment.

Answer (score 3):

Gnome already does this.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> allows you to draw the rectangle to capture.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> captures the active window on the screen.
- <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> captures the entire screen.

It saves to your Pictures directory. You can change the save directory using dconf-editor.

No dialog, no GUI. Just a flash to provide you feedback that the image was captured.

Comment: I don't use the gnome desktop environment

Comment: "I don' t use the gnome desktop": How is that clear from your question? Other desktops usually also have something like this.